# Workbox refresh button just one directory

Tags: caching, workbox

im new here (just start to learn js for this job and my english is not very good) and i'm having some trouble to find the right way to do this.

I'm working on a PWA that will have two main purposes, the first one is to show some html dashboards (one of the htmls dashboard files will be in this path /dashs/dash_geral.html) and the seccond one is to show some lists (e.g: one of them would be in this path /listas/listas_propostas.html), and the goal is to work offline (using cacheFirst strategy).
The problem is that i would want to reload just one folder of my two paths, i can do a "refresh all" in my index.html, but I would want to do it in another pages too, and in one page, i would refresh just one folder, in another page, i would refresh a seccond folder.

My scheme is something like this:

Index.html -> Install sw. Im my index.html body i have 2 big buttons, one to redirect to graphs (/graphs.html), another button to redirect to lists (/listas.html).

If i click in "graphs", i will be redirected to /graphs.html, and there i will have a topbar with a refresh button, one iframe to show different graphs (one of them is /dashs/dash_geral.html, so, when i call graphs.html he will use one of the dash htmls that i generated, i.e /dashs/dash_geral.html) and a navbar to navigate between another dashs (for example, if i click in "negocios" my iframe would load /dashs/dash_negocios.html).

[my graphs.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8X5W.png)

My goal is to click on refresh button, and update my cache of /dashs/*, ie, update my dashes from server to cache.
And do the same if i click in button lists, i would have the same structure, go to /listas.html, having a couple of htmls in /listas/* to navigate with my navbar, and if i click on reload i would want to refresh just that folder (/listas/*) on cache.

I already saw the advanced recipe to create a refresh button for clients, but i want two different refresh buttons with slightly different behaviours (one would "recache" /dash/*, and another /listas/*.
Besides that, my graphs.html and listas.html are not installing the sw.js, so i shouldn't have access to the main service worker if i'm not in my index.html page, right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, first of all I had misunderstood some stuffs.
I didnt understand before that, firts, if the connection drop, he will continue from the point it stopped (in precache strategy).
Seccond point i didnt understand, is that he will "listen" to all children folders inside scope, i thought that only if I went back to my start_url he will be called again.
I used revision parameter in precache solution to deal with files updates, i actually generate a new SW (with another program) an just change a few lines (the constants used in revision parameters) to update my files.
With those to points working, I can actually work with my app without a reload button, since every time i navigate between pages, he will be listening and recaching updates.